# Iterate JSON and get fields from JSON

Tags: java, json, loops

I've tried different solutions but I'm not able to iterate through this JSON and/or get direct specific values.

Could any one help on:

- Iterating through all the fields sequentially.
- Getting direct access to some fields (eg. when getting this response, access directly to `"packet-count"` where its value equals `3281`).

```
{"flow-node-inventory:flow":[{"id":"42","priority":10,"table_id":0,"opendaylight-flow-statistics:flow-statistics":{"packet-count":3281,"byte-count":317738,"duration":{"nanosecond":252000000,"second":3432}},"idle-timeout":10000,"cookie":31,"instructions":{"instruction":[{"order":0,"apply-actions":{"action":[{"order":0,"output-action":{"output-node-connector":"1","max-length":0}}]}}]},"match":{"ethernet-match":{"ethernet-source":{"address":"00:00:00:00:00:02"},"ethernet-destination":{"address":"00:00:00:00:00:01"}}},"hard-timeout":50000,"flags":""}]}
```

I tried to use `org.json` but any other library would be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check the structure of your JSON Object and create a structure for the entities you encounter accordingly. For instance, the first thing in your JSON object is an array, so this is the first thing you should care about. Imagine it as a continuous encapsulation. Check the code below for more information.

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(stringJson);
JSONArray flowNodeInv = jobj.getJSONArray("flow-node-inventory:flow");
    for (int i = 0; i < flowNodeInv.length(); i++){
          JSONObject segment = (JSONObject) flowNodeInv.get(i);
          JSONObject stats = segment.getJSONObject("opendaylight-flow-statistics:flow-statistics");

        int number = stats.getInt("packet-count");

       System.out.println("packet-count: "+ number);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
jObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());
Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ) {
     String key = (String)keys.next();
    if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that but what happens is that in the first print inside the "while" i get 
" flow-node-inventory:flow " (with no quotes) and it never gets inside the "if"


<code>
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stringJson);
    obj = new JSONObject(stringJson.trim());
    Iterator<?> keys = obj.keys();
    
    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        System.out.println(key);
        if ( obj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
     System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
<code>

Comment: It will definitely not go inside If block because the value of "flow-node-inventory:flow " is an array, not a JSON object.
You need to iterate over this array to process the remaining data.

Comment: (sorry not formatting the code in my answer but i wasn't able to...).  
That's my problem. I've not been able to do it. Can you give me a hand with it?  
 Thanks

Comment: Ok lets deep dive into your problem.
Which JSON parsing library you are using?

Answer (score 0):

To get direct access to the fields you can create a Java Object from the JSON String using an ObjectMappet (com.fasterxml.jackson). For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```